# Azure Portal - Cognitive Services monitoring issues

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a paid subscription for Azure's Cognitive Services.

I usually monitor the API traffic using the Cognitive Services > Metrics graph. This morning I noticed that no API calls appear on the metrics graph for the last 12 hours. 
This is particularly strange since trying to make an API call from an endpoint is successful, while also there are no alerts or notifications from Azure that something is wrong.

Screenshot attached.

Any ideas?[image]

Comment: sounds like a question to Azure Support to me

Comment: Agreed. I just opened a support ticket but thought maybe someone encountered this issue and got a magic solution...